# Set a value to a group of booleans

Tags: android, boolean

Let's say I have 14 booleans:

```
Boolean pressAnimationGroup[] = { pressAnimation1,
                    pressAnimation2, pressAnimation3, pressAnimation4,
                    pressAnimation5, pressAnimation6, pressAnimation7,
                    pressAnimation8, pressAnimation9, pressAnimation10,
                    pressAnimation11, pressAnimation12, pressAnimation13,
                    pressAnimation14 };
```

Can I set, let's say the `true` value to all of them without assigning to each one of them the `true` value?

Something like this:

```
for (Boolean groupPress : pressAnimationGroup) {
                // Assign to groupPress the true value
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.fill`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) which fills the specified array with the specified element.

```
Arrays.fill(pressAnimationGroup, true);
```

Comment: @BugaIulian Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna fill `true` then you can use what **Giru Bhai** has suggested.

In case you are using `false` then do nothing since `boolean` is by default `false` in java.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the tip.